# Powering an ESP32 board from external source issue

Tags: power-supply, esp32

If I connect my ESP32 board to my PC via USB and upload any code via the Arduino IDE, all works fine.

Even if I disconnect the USB cable, when I reconnect it, the ESP32 board restarts and works perfectly.

If I disconnect the USB cable and power the ESP32 board by means a reliable power source (https://www.tek.com/en/products/keithley/dc-power-supplies/2220-2230-2231-series) either from Vin (5V) or 3.3 V, the ESP32 board doesn't work in any way even though the onboard LED is ON.

In detail:

The ESP32 acts as a BLE server to which a BLE client is connected configured on another ESP32 board running under Home Assistant.

Powering via USB, the BLE server sends data to the BLE client on Home Assistant.  When I disconnect the USB cable from the PC  and connect the ESP32 to an external power source it stops sending data in any way.

Any idea?

```
    void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(25,OUTPUT);

  Serial.println("Visualizza quanto trasmesso dal BLE Client a questo BLE Server: ");
 
  BLEDevice::init("MyESP32-Cosimo");
  BLEServer *pServer = BLEDevice::createServer();

  BLEService *pService = pServer->createService(SERVICE_UUID);

  BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(
                                         CHARACTERISTIC_UUID,
                                         BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ |
                                         BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE
                                       );

  pCharacteristic->setCallbacks(new MyCallbacks());

  //pCharacteristic->setValue("Hello World");
  std::string value = "Hello World";
  pCharacteristic->setValue(value);
  pService->start();

  BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising = pServer->getAdvertising();
  pAdvertising->start();
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  delay(2000);
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: More information is needed. Assuming you are using an ESP32 devboard, which one is it ? What is the Vin that you are referring to ?

Comment: @mpetitjean
You're right. I've just added a photo...

Comment: Do you also have the part number / reference of the board ?

Comment: @mpetitjean I've found only this

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? The lights are on as you expect, so what behavior indicates to you a problem? Please describe in detail the expected and observed behaviors.

Comment: When you power it from VIN, what voltage do you get on the input pin of the LDO and on the +3V3 pin?

Comment: Do you by any chance have something like `while (!Serial) ;` in your setup or loop?

Comment: @TypeIA I've updated issue description

Comment: @DamienD
I've added the code

Comment: To debug things further I would blink the LED in the `loop` function, so you know if it's actually running.

Comment: @bobflux Hi. Wich is the input pin of the LDO ?

Comment: @DamienD Hi. I've tried but the results are the same

Comment: What do you mean by 'the same'? From my perspective it can mean it does blink or it doesn't blink. You have to be clearer in your descriptions ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

It was only a bad ESP32 board .

It works when powered by USB and don't in anyway if powered by external source.
Replacing it with a new, identical, board, it works fine even if is powered by 5V than 3,3 V.